# Склонировать репозиторий в папку с файлами

Tags: linux, git, bash, github

Всем привет.

Мне нужно склонировать репозиторий с GitHub в уже существующую директорию с заменой файлов. Обычный `$ git clone <link>` не помогает. Так как клонировать можно только в пустые директории.

Я нашел решение которое почти мне помогло. Нужно склонировать репозиторий во временную папку `git clone <link> tmp` а потом перетащить от туда все файлы. Вот как раз это у меня и не получается.

Вот моя последовательность действий.

1. `git clone <link> tmp`
2. `mv tmp/* dist`

Когда я выполняю второй шаг у меня переносятся только папки, а такие файлы как .git остаются на месте.

Как можно перенести все файлы из папки tmp в текущую директорию вместе с dotfiles?

Comment: `$ mv tmp/.git* dist`

Comment: По-хорошему вам надо добавлять `remote`, из которой получать `orphan branch`.